# Android check internet connection with BroadcastReceiver refresh current fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-broadcast

I am trying to check internet connection with BroadcastReceiver. I wrote some code to check internet connection. Below is my source code

```
    public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        boolean isMobile = false, isWifi = false;

        NetworkInfo[] infoAvailableNetworks = getConnectivityManagerInstance(
                context).getAllNetworkInfo();

        if (infoAvailableNetworks != null) {
            for (NetworkInfo network : infoAvailableNetworks) {

                if (network.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    if (network.isConnected() && network.isAvailable())
                        isWifi = true;
                }
                if (network.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                    if (network.isConnected() && network.isAvailable())
                        isMobile = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return isMobile || isWifi;
    }

   @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) 
                {
             Toast.makeText(context, "Network Available Do operations",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 


    }

}
```

Now I want to use my BroadcastReceiver in fragment. I am trying  to refresh fragment when internet connection is not available. I don't know how to refresh my fragment.
if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: If you want to reload the data displayed by your `Fragment`, you can use a `Loader` in your fragment to load the data and the loader would include the BroadcastReceiver which will call `onContentChange()` to trigger a reload.

Comment: i understood how to reload fragment but tell me how i can  to call my  onReceive method in fragment ? @Tauqir

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fragment transaction to rebuild and display your fragment. TAke a look at this [tutorial](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/04/android-fragment-transaction.html).

Comment: i understood how to reload fragment but tell me how i can  to call my  onReceive method in fragment ?

Comment: you can call the onresume/onpause methods in your fragment class to register/unregister the  receiver. But you need to create a class to handle that event